# Logger (SLF4J) breaking when upgrading to scala 2.13 and play 2.8

Tags: scala, gradle, playframework, slf4j

While upgrading to scala 2.13, my logger class is breaking as shown below:

```
val ctx = loggerFactory.asInstanceOf[LoggerContext]
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.scala.ScalaMethod.invoke(ScalaMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.run.PlayRunAdapterV26X.runDevHttpServer(PlayRunAdapterV26X.java:13)
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.startServer(PlayWorkerServer.java:81)
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.start(PlayWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.execute(PlayWorkerServer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.run.PlayWorkerServer.execute(PlayWorkerServer.java:21)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
        at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.playframework.tools.internal.scala.ScalaMethod.invoke(ScalaMethod.java:33)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory cannot be cast to class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext (org.slf4j.helpers.NOPLoggerFactory and ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext are in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @503f91c3)
        at play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.configure(LogbackLoggerConfigurator.scala:91)
        at play.api.libs.logback.LogbackLoggerConfigurator.init(LogbackLoggerConfigurator.scala:31)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.$anonfun$mainDev$1(DevServerStart.scala:106)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:22)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:76)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:50)
        ... 15 more
```

Can someone help me figure out the appropriate fix for the same?

This is my `slf4j` dependency:

`api group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'log4j-over-slf4j', version: '2.0.9'`

Here's the initial logs:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/Users/shivamsahil/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.12/d4dee19148dccb177a0736eb2027bd195341da78/logback-classic-1.2.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
Failed to run Play
```

Comment: Looks like at the very least, you need to provide an slf4j implementation (log4j-over-slf4j, as you probably know, is not an slf4j implementation). Though based on the error, it would appear Play Framework insists you use logback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play Framework SLF4J Error Wehn Starting Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77054814/play-framework-slf4j-error-wehn-starting-server)

Comment: What does your build definition looks like? What do SLF4J logs say at startup?

Comment: @GaëlJ I have added initial logs.

Comment: @GastónSchabas It is similar to this but I am not sure how I can enforce a specific version for existing dependencies as well, tried adding:
`api "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9"` but didn't work

Comment: It seems you are using Gradle? You should look about how to do it with Gradle but the idea is the same as the link posted by @GastónSchabas indeed. And the initial logs tell you exactly that: "No SLF4J providers found", "Ignoring logback 1.2", "bindings for SLF4J 1.7.x found".

Comment: Before the update also I used to get the same logs except the part: `bindings for SLF4J 1.7.x found`. But yes trying to implement the same in Gradle should be something that should work.